# How do I create a canvas circle with a triangle inside it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to create a canvas with a circle, and inside the circle should be a triangle. I know how to draw a simple circle (below), but how do I put in the triangle?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.beginPath();
context.arc(75,100,55,0,2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to draw a triangle inside a circle you need to calculate the positions of the vertices. Supposing that your triangle is equilateral the angle between vertices is 120degs or 2*Math.PI/3:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let cw = canvas.width = 300;// the width of the canvas
let ch = canvas.height = 300;// the height of the canvas

let c={// the circle: coords of the center and the radius
  x:75,y:100,r:55
}

let angle = (2*Math.PI)/3;// the angle between vertices

points = [];// the vertices array
   

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  let o = {}
  o.x = c.x + c.r*Math.cos(i*angle);
  o.y = c.y + c.r*Math.sin(i*angle);
  points.push(o); 
}

// draw the circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(c.x,c.y,c.r,0,2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();


// draw the triangle
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
for(let i = 1; i < points.length; i++){
  context.lineTo(points[i].x,points[i].y);
}
context.closePath();
context.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @pordix Yes, I suppose, but I would need more details. The circle should spin around what. Please ask another question with all the details. I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines before calling `stroke`

```
context.moveTo(75,75);
context.lineTo(100, 100);
context.lineTo(25,150);
context.lineTo(75,75);
```

It is coming out of the cirle a little bit, but you get the idea.